# Is Dart mirror behavior to not allow invocation of private methods from other libraries guaranteed and part of the spec?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

if I have 2 files:

bin.dart:

```dart
import 'lib.dart';
import 'dart:mirrors';

/*
class Foo{
  bool _bar() => true;
}
*/

void main() {
  var foo = new Foo();
  print(reflect(foo).invoke(#_bar, []));
}
```

lib.dart:

```dart
library lib;

class Foo{
  bool _bar() => true;
}
```

If I run bin.dart I get what I hope to happen, an exception when trying to invoke a private method. but if I comment out the `import 'lib.dart'` line and uncomment the local Foo definition this timeit runs without exception, which I suppose is ok because now the private mthod is being invoked from the declaring library. So my question is, is the behavior guaranteed? I need to make sure that a point of invocation via mirrors in my library will not allow the invocation of private members from other libraries, presently I explicitly check this by doing a check for a names starting with _:

```dart
if(MirrorSystem.getName(inv.method).startsWith('_')){
  throw new RestrictedMethodError(inv.method);
}else{
  _this.invoke(inv.method, inv.posArgs, inv.namArgs);
}
```

however if the privacy is still respected even by mirrors by default then I can get rid of this check and remove the import for dart:mirrors in my library, thanks.

### UPDATE

What if the symbol `inv.method` was guaranteed to always be derived from:

```dart
inv.method = MirrorSystem.getSymbol(stringName);
```

would this then prevent the private method from being called as in the file `dart:mirrors-patch_mirrors_patch.dart` line 92:

```dart
  static Symbol getSymbol(String name,[LibraryMirror library]) {
    if((library != null && library is !_LocalLibraryMirror) ||
       ((name.length > 0) && (name[0] == "_") && (library == null))) {
      throw new ArgumentError(library);
    }
    if (library != null) name = _mangleName(name, library._reflectee);
    return new _symbol_dev.Symbol.unvalidated(name);
  }
```

will do the test to check it doesn't start with underscore, so will prevent any "private symbols" from being generated if you can guarantee that all the symbols are being generated in this fashion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflection allows you to overcome all privacy mechanisms. So no, you can not rely on it. Think of "_foo" as "foo" prefixed by a library-token that users cannot generate. As such, `#_bar` in the main-library is different from `#_bar` in the `lib` library. However, you could just enumerate all identifiers of the given `foo` object and find the private function.

If you need real privacy you need to use isolates.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a private symbol by iterating the keys of ClassMirror.instanceMembers or ClassMirror.staticMembers. So no, you cannot prevent the creation of private symbols.